# Iptables PREROUTING to redirect port 80 through varnish for selected IP

Tags: iptables, varnish

I have installed varnish on my server and would like to test the configuration without affecting normal usage. I have apache listening on port 80 and varnish on port 8080. So, I want all requests from my IP a.b.c.d to pass through varnish and all the other IPs should be allowed to access apache normally.

I read somewhere that it is possible to use PREROUTING in Iptables to achieve this. Can some one please tell me how to do it? I have 2 sites hosted on the server, is it possible to configure this for just one domain?

**Update**
I tried the command, but it did not work

```
root@git:~# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i venet0 -p tcp -s 117.201.192.67 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
root@git:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@git:~# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i venet0:0 -p tcp -s 117.201.192.67 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
Warning: weird character in interface `venet0:0' (No aliases, :, ! or *).
root@git:~# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -s 117.201.192.67 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
root@git:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I am on a VPS and do not have an interface named `eth0`. `/sbin/ifconfig` lists `lo`, `venet0`, `venet0:0`, `venet0:1` and `venet0:2` only.

**Update 2** - Inserting the rule at the beginning worked

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -s 117.201.192.67  --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```

Is it possible to check the requested hostname too? I would like to redirect only requests for mydomainname.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify source address (or network) in an iptables redirect as follows:

> iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

The rules are read from top to bottom, and first match goes, so you might have to stick it in the right place.

Comment: I am new to iptables. How can I configure it to redirect only requests from the ipaddress a.b.c.d?

Comment: Add -s a.b.c.d to the rule.
-s means source of the packet.

Comment: Use `-I` to insert the rule at the beginning of the chain.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is it better to add `-i venet0`? Also is it possible to check the requested hostname too?